# How to order data in a dictionary in Python using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to sort my output by Perpetrator's Age in increasing order. At the moment, it is completely unordered.

I have tried to use the sort function but it does not work.

```
    xl = pd.ExcelFile('Murders.xlsx')
    df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
    age = df['Perpetrator Age']

    freq1 = collections.Counter(df['Perpetrator Age'])
    freq = [{'Perpetrator_Age': m, 'Freq': f} for m, f in freq1.items()]
    file = open("MurderPerpAge.js", "w+")
    file.write(json.dumps(freq))
    file.close()
```

I expect my output to be ordered by the age from youngest to oldest.

```
[{"Perpetrator_Age": 15, "Freq": 5441}, {"Perpetrator_Age": 17, "Freq": 14196},...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: Pure python

Try `sorted` with key:

```
sorted(freq , key=lambda x: x["Perpetrator_Age"])
```

## Option 2: Mixed Pandas and pure python

```
freq1 = Counter(df['Perpetrator Age'].sort_values())
freq = [{'Perpetrator_Age': m, 'Freq':f} for m,f in freq1.items()]
```

## Option 3: Pure Pandas

Inspired by WeNYoBen's answer.

```
freq1 = df.groupby('Perpetrator Age').size()
freq1.name = 'Freq'
freq = freq1.reset_index().to_dict('r')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @treatyoself on which solution? there was an error in solution 3 where `groupby('Perpetrator_Age')` should be `groupby('Perpetrator Age')`.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to specify.  For Option 2, I got the error.

Comment: It ran fine with my toy dataset `df = pd.DataFrame({"Perpetrator Age": np.random.randint(15,50,1000)})` . Can you check if your `df['Perpetrator Age']` contains string values?

Comment: I'm reading from an xlsx file. I filtered through the data and did find some values that were "Blanks". Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it is the problem since `df['Perpetrator Age'].sort_values()` will try to compare "Blanks" and the `int` values and throw that error. Other solutions would be fine, "Blank" counts will be the last in the `freq` list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193177/discussion-between-treatyoself-and-quang-hoang).

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned `pandas` , I am using `value_counts` , since the default is sort by freq

```
df['Perpetrator Age'].value_counts().reset_index().to_dict('r')
```

Comment: Good one. I was looking at `to_dict` too, and learned a new thing from your answer with `to_dict('r')`.